# Error in 'SqlQuery' method is not natively supported by your database provider

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework-core, ef-core-7.0

In function execution calls of dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<T> the following exception:

> 'The element type 'MyEntity' used in 'SqlQuery' method is not natively supported by your database provider. Either use a supported element type, or use ModelConfigurationBuilder.DefaultTypeMapping to define a mapping for your type.'

[Exception details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHSjK.png)

The source code.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders;

namespace Test
{
    public class Employee
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
    public class EmployeeInfo
    {
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class EmployeeDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
        public EmployeeDBContext() { }
        public EmployeeDBContext(DbContextOptions<EmployeeDBContext> options)
            : base(options) { }

        protected override void ConfigureConventions(ModelConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder)
        {
            base.ConfigureConventions(configurationBuilder);

            //Action<TypeMappingConfigurationBuilder<EmployeeInfo>> actionEmployeeInfo = (buildAction) => { };
            //configurationBuilder.DefaultTypeMapping(actionEmployeeInfo);
            //Action<TypeMappingConfigurationBuilder> action = (buildAction) => { };
            //configurationBuilder.DefaultTypeMapping(typeof(EmployeeInfo), action);
            //configurationBuilder.DefaultTypeMapping(typeof(EmployeeInfo));
            configurationBuilder.DefaultTypeMapping<EmployeeInfo>();
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Data source=localhost;Database=EmployeeDB;User Id=sa;Password=Dev.NET;");
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>(builder => builder.HasKey(x => x.Id));
        }
    }
}
```

The Test code.

```
using FluentAssertions;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace Test
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class EmployeeTest
    {
        [Test(Description = nameof(Find_Employee_ReturnModel))]
        public void Find_Employee_ReturnModel()
        {
            // Arrange
            var dbContext = new EmployeeDBContext();
            dbContext.Database.EnsureDeleted();
            dbContext!.Database.EnsureCreated();

            var employee = new Employee { FirstName = "Joao", LastName = "Gomes" };
            dbContext.Employees.Add(employee);
            dbContext.SaveChanges();

            // Act
            var employeeInfo = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<EmployeeInfo>($"SELECT e.Id as EmployeeId, e.FirstName as Name FROM Employee e").ToList();

            // Assert
            employeeInfo.Should().HaveCount(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Added recommended settings to return a type that is not natively supported by the database provider.

[DefaultTypeMapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSOLO.png)

```
protected override void ConfigureConventions(ModelConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder)
        {
            base.ConfigureConventions(configurationBuilder);

            //Action<TypeMappingConfigurationBuilder<EmployeeInfo>> actionEmployeeInfo = (buildAction) => { };
            //configurationBuilder.DefaultTypeMapping(actionEmployeeInfo);
            //Action<TypeMappingConfigurationBuilder> action = (buildAction) => { };
            //configurationBuilder.DefaultTypeMapping(typeof(EmployeeInfo), action);
            //configurationBuilder.DefaultTypeMapping(typeof(EmployeeInfo));
            configurationBuilder.DefaultTypeMapping<EmployeeInfo>();
        }
```

Comment: "SqlQuery allows you to easily query for *scalar*, non-entity types via SQL" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/sql-queries#querying-scalar-non-entity-types

Comment: Right, thanks for the answer.
But is there any way to return an entity by this method?

Because to work around this, I'm returning in json format "**for json path**" in SqlQuery, and deserializing in the application.

Example: `dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<string>($"SELECT e.Id as EmployeeId, e.FirstName as Name FROM Employee e for json path").ToList();`

Comment: This is planned in EF 8 (Nov. 2023): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-8.0/plan#sql-queries-for-unmapped-types

Answer (score 7):

Not exactly a solution but a workaround until EF8 comes:

```cs
statement += " for json path";
var asJson = string.Join("", _context.Database.SqlQueryRaw<string>(statement)); 
return System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TModel[]>(asJson);
```

Comment: Seems like this is the only way this can work. Thanks loads

Answer (score 7):

```
 EmployeeDetail detail =  _dbContext.EmployeeDetail.FromSqlInterpolated($"exec [dbo].[SPName] @Id = {Id}").ToList();
```

Add Model to DBContext

```
  public virtual DbSet<EmployeeDetail> EmployeeDetails{ get; set; }
```

Add [Keyless] to the Model definition

```
 [Keyless]
public  class EmployeeDetail
{
    public int Name{ get; set; }
```

Comment: Best answer, pre-EF 8

Comment: What would be the best answer after EF 8/in EF Core